# How to input and output names in JOptionPane in Java

Tags: java

I am making a program that inputs and outputs names using `JOptionPane`.

What should I do if I am done inputting the name to automatically go back to the menu and pick a choice again so I can choose and view my inputted name in my display name section?

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("[1] Insert Name\n[2] Display Name"));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Names: "+values[i]);
```

```
public static void main (String args []) {

    String [] values = new String [10];
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("[1] Insert Name\n[2] Display Name"));

    if (choice == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
            values[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Your Name: ");
        }   
    }

    if (choice == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Names: "+values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't know how many names you will have, use a List.
Then you must loop over all Strings when displaying so will display all of them. Your loop was just iterating over the first element.

Also, when adding a name you must add it and not overwrite the first one. If you want to return to your selection, you need to use a loop.

The following code should work, but I think you should get to know basic control structures before starting to code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> nameList = new LinkedList<String>();

    while (true) {  // Repeat forever
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("[1] Insert Name\n[2] Display Names"));

        if (choice == 1) 
            nameList.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Your Name: "));

        if (choice == 2) 
            for (String name: nameList)  // loop over all strings in the list
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+ name);
    }
}
```

Note however, that you need to `import java.util.LinkedList;` for this to work.